# Все, кто делает (или делают)?

Tags: спряжение

Возник вопрос, который до этого никогда не беспокоил мое сознание. В подобном обороте "все, кто + глагол" сказуемое ставится в ед. числе или множественном?

Все, кто думает. Все, кто думают... 
Все, кто может ходить. Все, кто могут ходить.

Единственное?

Comment: "Все, кто делают", но "Каждый, кто делает".

Comment: Предложение "Все, кто делают ..." подразумевает предложение "Каждый, кто делает ...".

Comment: То, что подразумевается, - это нечто отдаленное и смутно-неясное, а в существующей реальности надо обеспечить гармоничное согласование слов в ед. числе.

Comment: Милая София.

Поверьте мне на слово, что глаголы "подразумевать" (to imply) и "означать" (to mean) являются глаголами русского метаязыка.

Пример

Предложение "Пингвин не летает." подразумевает предложение "Если стриж не бегает, то пингвин не летает.".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Основной вариант - это ед. число, например: Все, кто еще не потерял головы, были против. Те, кто раньше учился в училищах, стали хорошими специалистами. (Варианты "ВСЕ, КТО и ТЕ, КТО" кажутся нормальным на слух).

ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЯ

1. ФОРМАЛЬНОЕ согласование: ПЕРВЫЕ, КТО записались в кружок, уже начали заниматься. В студенческих аудиториях СИДЯТ ТЕ, КТО лет десять назад были школярами. В приведенных примерах согласование во мн.числе ЗАДАЕТСЯ изначально формой мн. числа для слов  "первые", "сидят".
2. СМЫСЛОВОЕ согласование: мн.число подчеркивает, что производителей действия было несколько: Все, кто стали призерами, получили награды. Но: Все, кто помнил события тех лет в деталях, уже умерли (используется ед. число, если количество производителей не подчеркивается).

ПРАКТИКА

Практически форма мн. числа встречается крайне редко:

1) Все, кто стоял на дороге, замерли. Все, кто мог, прильнули к окошкам. Ого, приехали все, кто обещал! Все, кто был в наличности, не находились при деле на своих местах, а ...смотрели на то, что делается под стеною Варьете.

2) Все, кто вскочили, заслышав тяжёлую походку Чуйкова, увидели, что командарм расстроен.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько мне известно, допустимы оба варианта, но предпочтительнее вариант с единственным числом: Все, кто думает... Все, кто может ходить... В тестах ЕГЭ вариант с ед.ч. считается правильным ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Вижу в языке и речевой практике дрейф ко множественному числу. Т.е. предсказываю, что лет через 40 нормой будет множественное, а единственное будет оцениваться как устаревшее.

Comment: Приведите примеры. Для согласования во мн.числе нет объективных причин: обычно после местоимения КТО непосредственно следует глагол, а он с местоимением согласуется в ед.числе:КТО ПРИШЁЛ. Это общее для языка правило согласования с ближайшим словом применяется и в придаточном предложении.

Comment: Извиняюсь и уточняю: имел в виду форму "все, кто..." и т.п.
Тогда для согласования есть объективные причины.
А вообще к объективным я бы относил и семантику, не только грамматику. "Смотрите, кто пришли..." -- не поручусь, что через 40 лет это не будет нормой (если пришедших много). Но это скорее ощущение, кто его знает, куда язык повернёт...

Answer (score 0):

Это самое распространенное непонимание у школьников
Здесь "Все" не относится к слову "думает". У нас думает КТО. А ВСЕ что-то другое делаЮТ.

Answer (score 0):

"Все, кто пришёл на собрание, были в галстуках." - сложно-подчинённое предложение: "Все... были в галстуках" - главное, "Все" - подлежащее, "были" - сказуемое; "кто пришёл на собрание" - придаточное: "кто" - подлежащее, выраженное местоимением ед. числа; "пришёл" - сказуемое, и не допустимо "кто пришли", т.к. это нарушает традиции русского языка,- здесь либо присвоение местоимению "кто" множественного числа, либо согласование с подлежащим другого предложения, что неправильно. Вот, если: "Все, *которые* пришли на собрание были в галстуках."

Comment: Очень путано и длинно. Не говорю уж об оригинальном понимании пунктуации.